# return data with chain static method

Tags: php

i'm trying to return data with chain static method , but i can't because the method return one thing only .

```
class Input
{
        public static function set($input)
        {
              $data = $input;
              $class = get_class();
              return $data;
              return self::$class = new $class;
        }
        public static function get()
        {
             echo ' - get method';
        }
}

Input::set('ahmed')->get();
```

but it's only print " -get method "

Comment: that's all you're telling it to print. What did you expect?

Comment: actually what is the result you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
class Input
{
    private static $data;

    public static function set($input)
    {
        self::$data = $input;
        return self;
    }

    public static function get()
    {
        echo self::$data.' - get method';
    }
}

Input::set('ahmed')->get(); // ahmed - get method
```

but this you can use only once better is set name for value

```
class Input
{
    private static $data = array();

    public static function set($name, $input)
    {
        self::$data[$name] = $input;
        return self;
    }

    public static function get($name)
    {
        echo self::$data[$name].' - get method';
    }
}


Input::set('name', 'ahmed')->get('name'); // ahmed - get method
```